# Raspbian - Can't spoof a MAC address through HostAPD

Tags: wireless-networking, raspberry-pi, raspbian, hostapd

I'm trying to let my Raspberry Pi function as an access point, but I keep running into some problems. Specifically when it comes to spoofing the MAC address.
The purpose is to create a Nintendo 3DS [streetpass hotspot](http://nintendo.wikia.com/wiki/StreetPass) at home. I'm following [this guide](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1EvmIwTIjPva5MHSFEIN0qsHtRmdRRiX3WNHu_ThxnOs/) mostly.

First the things I'm using:
Raspberry Pi Model B with a [TP-Link TL-WN725N v2](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_TL-WN725N_v2) wireless usb adapter with Realtek RTL8188EUS chipset. This one is [recommended](http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters) for AR purposes.

Kernel running on Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 installed through NOOBS v1.3.9 (2014-07-08):

```
Linux raspberrypi 3.12.22+ #691 PREEMPT Wed Jun 18 18:29:58 BST 2014 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

`lsusb` on the wlan adapter:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
```

I installed the driver through [this guide](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=462982). Running `iwlist wlan0 scan` succesfully returns a list of wireless networks.
Then I moved on to installing the necessary packages. First I installed HostAPD through [this guide](http://jenssegers.be/blog/43/realtek-rtl8188-based-access-point-on-raspberry-pi), but running into some problems (got an the error `ioctl[RTL_IOCTL_HOSTAPD]: Invalid argument`) I tried what was suggested [here](https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=47716#p240781). With success.
After this I installed both the packages isc-dhcp-server and bridge-utils.

I made a test config file for hostapd (/tmp/test.conf):

```
# Basic configuration

interface=wlan0
ssid=wifi
bssid=4E:53:50:4F:4F:46
channel=5
bridge=br0

# WPA and WPA2 configuration

macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0

# Hardware configuration

driver=rtl871xdrv
ieee80211n=1
hw_mode=g
device_name=RTL8192CU
manufacturer=Realtek
```

After running hostapd /tmp/test.conf I'm getting the following error (part of the return):

```
+rtl871x_sta_deauth_ops, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff is deauth, reason=2
Using interface wlan0 with hwaddr e8:94:f6:1c:4a:dd and ssid 'wifi'
```

It falls back to it's real MAC address.
Running a debug returns the following:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# hostapd -dd /tmp/test.conf
random: Trying to read entropy from /dev/random
Configuration file: /tmp/test.conf
drv->ifindex=3
Configure bridge br0 for EAPOL traffic.
BSS count 1, BSSID mask a6:c7:a6:53:05:9b (0 bits)
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=1 freq=2412 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=2 freq=2417 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=3 freq=2422 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=4 freq=2427 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=5 freq=2432 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=6 freq=2437 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=7 freq=2442 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=8 freq=2447 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=9 freq=2452 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=10 freq=2457 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=11 freq=2462 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=12 freq=2467 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=13 freq=2472 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=14 freq=2484 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=1 freq=2412 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=2 freq=2417 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=3 freq=2422 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=4 freq=2427 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=5 freq=2432 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=6 freq=2437 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=7 freq=2442 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=8 freq=2447 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=9 freq=2452 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=10 freq=2457 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=11 freq=2462 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=36 freq=5180 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=40 freq=5200 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=44 freq=5220 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=48 freq=5240 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=52 freq=5260 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=56 freq=5280 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=60 freq=5300 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=64 freq=5320 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=100 freq=5500 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=104 freq=5520 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=108 freq=5540 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=112 freq=5560 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=116 freq=5580 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=120 freq=5600 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=124 freq=5620 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=128 freq=5640 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=132 freq=5660 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=136 freq=5680 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=140 freq=5700 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=149 freq=5745 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=153 freq=5765 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=157 freq=5785 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=161 freq=5805 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=165 freq=5825 MHz max_tx_power=0 dBm
Completing interface initialization
Mode: IEEE 802.11g  Channel: 5  Frequency: 2432 MHz
RATE[0] rate=10 flags=0x1
RATE[1] rate=20 flags=0x1
RATE[2] rate=55 flags=0x1
RATE[3] rate=110 flags=0x1
RATE[4] rate=60 flags=0x0
RATE[5] rate=90 flags=0x0
RATE[6] rate=120 flags=0x0
RATE[7] rate=180 flags=0x0
RATE[8] rate=240 flags=0x0
RATE[9] rate=360 flags=0x0
RATE[10] rate=480 flags=0x0
RATE[11] rate=540 flags=0x0
Flushing old station entries
Deauthenticate all stations
+rtl871x_sta_deauth_ops, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff is deauth, reason=2
rtl871x_set_key_ops
rtl871x_set_key_ops
rtl871x_set_key_ops
rtl871x_set_key_ops
Using interface wlan0 with hwaddr e8:94:f6:1c:4a:dd and ssid 'wifi'
rtl871x_set_wps_assoc_resp_ie
rtl871x_set_wps_beacon_ie
rtl871x_set_wps_probe_resp_ie
rtl871x_set_beacon_ops
rtl871x_set_hidden_ssid ignore_broadcast_ssid:0, wifi,4
rtl871x_set_acl
wlan0: Setup of interface done.
random: Got 20/20 bytes from /dev/random
```

I searched and searched but whatever I try, it keeps going back to the original bssid. What can I do to get this running the way I want it to?

Just a heads-up: I'm new to linux.

edit: as requested the output of `ifconfig`

```
root@raspberrypi:~# ifconfig
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:3b:a6:3d
          inet addr:192.168.1.110  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ba27:ebff:fe3b:a63d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:835 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:364 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:183402 (179.1 KiB)  TX bytes:33584 (32.7 KiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:3b:a6:3d
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:835 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:364 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:183558 (179.2 KiB)  TX bytes:37524 (36.6 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e8:94:f6:1c:4a:dd
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

`iw list` returns `command not found` but the `iwlist` command is available if they even share a similar purpose.

edit2: I installed `iw`. Running `iw list` returns this:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# iw list
nl80211 not found.
```

Comment: I can’t answer your question right away, but the `BSSID` option is not what you’re looking for. And cross-posting is a no-no. ;) /edit: Ah yes, and please post the output of `ifconfig` and `iw list`.

Comment: I apologize for the cross-posting. I figured they had different user-bases, so it wouldn't be a problem. I can delete one if needed.
I posted the output of `ifconfig`, but `iw` is not an available command to me.

Comment: I installed the `iw` package. Post updated.

Comment: I see. Well, I naturally assumed your adapter would be using the kernel WiFi framework. If that isn’t the case, I can’t help you at all, sorry.